# SQL Server 2016 - Bitwise vs multiple bit columns

Tags: sql-server, bitwise-operators

I'm working with a SQL Server database that currently uses an integer field to categorize jobs using bitwise operators.

I assumed this would be a performance bottleneck, so started investigating splitting this column up into multiple indexed bit columns. However after doing some tests, I've noticed some unusual results. The bitwise queries are outperforming the bit columns.

These are my two queries I'm testing...

```
declare @HotJob int = 32;
declare @FeaturedJob int = 64;

select * from Job
where (JobType&@HotJob)=@HotJob
and (JobType&@FeaturedJob)=0;

select * from Job
where HotJob = 1
and FeaturedJob = 0;
```

The query analyzer reports that the relative costs are 28% to 72%.

The table is relatively small, only 25K rows.

Can anyone suggest why this would be the case?

I have no problem with keeping the bitwise column, but was just curious as to why exactly it performs better, when everything I've read seems to suggest separate columns should work better.

Comment: Have you looked at the query plans for these? I feel like the second one might end up doing a key lookup, but I could never repro that without some effort.

Comment: For the bitwise query, it's doing a key lookup, and index scan. For the non-bitwise query, it's doing just a clustered index scan.

Comment: I've tried a few other combinations in the where, returning various numbers of columns, and while the difference isn't isn't always significant, the bitwise versions are always less costly.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead of accessing the multiple columns seems to be larger than that of a single column. However, with the normalized columns, you can create indexes that may be useful, avoiding a full scan.  The relative costs (which I take with a grain of salt) are 91% and 9% with the covering index example below. You may need to experiment since the optimal indexing will vary depending on your queries and data.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.JobBitMask(
      JobID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_JobBitMask PRIMARY KEY
    , JobType int NOT NULL
    , JobData varchar(100) NOT NULL
    );

WITH 
     t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t256 AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d)
    ,t16M AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num FROM t256 AS a CROSS JOIN t256 AS b CROSS JOIN t256 AS c)
INSERT INTO dbo.JobBitMask WITH (TABLOCKX) (JobID, JobType, JobData) 
SELECT num, CASE num%10 WHEN 0 THEN 32 ELSE 0 END + CASE num%3 WHEN 0 THEN 64 ELSE 0 END, 'other data'
FROM t16M
WHERE num <= 25000;

CREATE TABLE dbo.JobNormalized(
      JobID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_JobNormalized PRIMARY KEY
    , HotJob bit NOT NULL
    , FeaturedJob bit NOT NULL
    , JobData varchar(100) NOT NULL
    );
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON dbo.JobNormalized(HotJob, FeaturedJob) INCLUDE(JobData);

WITH 
      t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    , t256 AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d)
    , t16M AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num FROM t256 AS a CROSS JOIN t256 AS b CROSS JOIN t256 AS c)
INSERT INTO dbo.JobNormalized WITH (TABLOCKX) (JobID, HotJob, FeaturedJob, JobData)
SELECT num, CASE num%10 WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, CASE num%3 WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 'other data'
FROM t16M
WHERE num <= 25000;

CREATE INDEX idx ON dbo.JobNormalized(HotJob, FeaturedJob) INCLUDE(JobData);

DECLARE @HotJob int = 32;
DECLARE @FeaturedJob int = 64;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.JobBitMask
WHERE (JobType&@HotJob)=@HotJob
AND (JobType&@FeaturedJob)=0;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.JobNormalized
WHERE HotJob = 1
AND FeaturedJob = 0;
```